# How to reduce the number of collisions?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am developing a routing algorithm for the vehicular network.

However, some collisions are preventing resend of the message at times.

I would like to know if in VEINS when there are collisions, if it relays messages automatically if any feature is enabled? Or should I handle the message retransmission in my routing algorithm in **MyVeinsApp.cc** that will abstract the necessary resources from the WAVE MAC layer? Or simply change the backoff used?

My problem is similar to that described in this old links:

https://sourceforge.net/p/sumo/mailman/message/28130474/

[Some Messages are lost in veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756168/some-messages-are-lost-in-veins)

When I send a message that must be forwarded, I define a backoff as follows:

```
backoff = uniform(0.01,0.001);
sendDelayedDown(frame->dup(), backoff);
```

Development environment used: SUMO 1.2.0, VEINS 5.0 and OMNet++ 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Veins support unicast transmissions using explicit acknowledgement messages. If no acknowledgement message is received, the transmission is retried. See, for example, the [relevant source code of Veins 5.0](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc#L60).

Comment: I am using only one channel in the communication. Do I need to enable something in the omnetpp.ini file?